# Зачем в кортежах в конце ставят запятую?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В Python часто кортежи объявляются как:

```
some_tuple = (
    val1,
    val2,
    val3,
)
```

Слышал, что не оставлять запятую в конце (после val3) считается плохой практикой.
Для чего это делается?

Comment: _Слышал, что ... считается плохой практикой_ - где слышал?

Comment: насколько нам объясняли на занятиях, что добавив значение если, то запятая уже есть. Что то типа готовое место. => вот из ссылки ниже ====> Вы можете добавлять элементы в конец или переставлять их, не нарушая синтаксис, поскольку случайно пропустили запятую. (именно так нам говорили)

Comment: Чтобы при добавлении четвёртого элемента дифф в гите более красивый был

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/what-is-the-syntax-rule-for-having-trailing-commas-in-tuple-definitions

Comment: Это примерно то же самое, что вместо слова "последний" использовать слово "крайний" :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще-то и списки можно так же объявлять.

```py
lst = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
]
```

И я считаю проставление "запасной" запятой хорошей практикой. По нескольким причинам:

1. Однообразие - все строчки в коллекции равноправны, их можно легко поменять местами или скопировать из другой коллекции, и не нужно думать, где при этом убрать запятую, а где добавить. Ставь запятую в конце каждой строчки, а Питон сам разберётся, какие запятые нужны, а какие нет.

```py
lst = [
    2,
    42,
    3,
    1,
]
```

2. Не будет проблемы, если это кортеж, вы удалили из него все элементы кроме последнего, забыли в конце добавить запятую, и это перестало быть кортежем. Если запятая есть в каждой строке, то удаляй любые строки, кортеж всё-равно сохранится.

```py
# это не кортеж с одним элементом 3, а просто значение 3
some_tuple = (
    3
)
```

3. Не будет проблемы с забытой запятой в коллекции строк (соседние строки в случае отсутствия запятой склеятся, а элементов в коллекции будет на 1 меньше, чем можно ожидать).

```py
# тут две строки, а не три: "1" и "32"
strings = [
    "1",
    "3"
    "2",
]
```

Comment: Становится очевидным, что это какой-то кривой способ объявления кортежа - забыл запятую(!), и всё пропало... Со списком всё более определённо. Какую альтернативу лучше использовать для объявления кортежа?

Comment: Когда-то начал изучать Руби. написал несколько утилит, а потом понял, что отсутствие типизации может принести в большом проекте столько головой боли! Известно, что люди как-то работают, но меня это не вдохновляет.

Comment: @rotabor По-моему это не лечится в Питоне, ну вот такой синтаксис придумали для кортежей. Мне это и самому не нравится, но теперь уж ничего не поделать. Можно извернуться, обернув в `tuple` определение списка, но это всё-равно какая-то кривизна )

Comment: @rotabor, _это какой-то кривой способ объявления кортежа - забыл запятую_ - только для одного элемента

Answer (score 4):

Всё очень банально - это для удобства вставки или удаления элементов строками.